# Using Delete request in Django outside of a form

Tags: ajax, django, html, httprequest

I am trying to create a simple todo list app that uses POST to post data into the data base and a 'x' (\u00D7) to delete the todo. The code is as following:

**Views.py**

```
def delete(self, request, id):
    print(request.DELETE)
    self.model.objects.get(pk=request.delete['pk']).delete()
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'object_list':self.model.objects.all()})
```

**Models.py**

```
class TodoDB(models.Model):
todos = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
day = models.CharField(max_length=10)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.todos)
```

**HTML and JS**

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="list-group">
      {%for item in object_list%}
        <li class="list-group-item">{{item.todos}}</li>
      {%endfor%}
</ul>


for (var i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = function() {
      var li = this.parentElement;
      li.style.display = "none";
      $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: "{%url 'todo_list'%}",
        data:{'pk':pk},
        success: function(data){
          alert("Success!");
        },
        error: function(){
          alert("Error! Couldn't send delete request")
        }
      });
  }
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

EDIT: I forgot to add the error: The error was csrf_token not found. I put the entire list under a new form tag and inserted a {%csrf_token%} in there, but it still doesn't accept the token.

Comment: So.. I assume you're getting an error? Could you post it? And if not, what works at the moment and what doesn't?

Comment: Please consider providing a template piece for that either. There is no `{%csrf_token%}` in your code

Answer (score 0):

Please consider reading 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/
on how it is made up in Django.
In brief you would need to render csrf token in your form and post it with AJAX during your request.
Your error is just about that.

`data:{'pk':pk},`
In your JS part should look something like:

```
data:{
    'pk':pk,
    'csrf_token': [your rendered token here...]
},
```